# Can Index set for a stochastic process be finite?

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition

Consider the following [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process#Index_set) for the index set for a stochastic process

> The set $T$ is called the index set or
>   parameter set of the stochastic process. Often this set is
>   some subset of the real line, such as the natural numbers or an
>   interval, giving the set $T$ the interpretation of
>   time. In addition to these sets, the index set $T$
>   can be other linearly ordered sets or more general mathematical
>   sets, such as the Cartesian plane $R^2$
>   or $R^n$, where an
>   element $t \in T$ can represent a point in
>   space. But in general more results and theorems are possible
>   for stochastic processes when the index set is ordered.

It is clear from the the definition that it can be infinite. Can the index set be finite?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the index set can be any set at all.  In general, a definition means nothing more or less than what it says, so if the definition calls $T$ just a set, then it can be any set.